# Unity interception policy returning proxy object

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, aop, castle-dynamicproxy

When resolving a dependency I want to return proxy, created with DynamicProxy instead of original object.

I cannot find the way how to do that in Unity.

Comment: I have no answer for you, just advice: Please learn about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and how to ask good questions. It would improve your chances to get good answers. :-)